How to config Message Filtering of Debezium connector for PostgreSQL?
Debezium provides the filter single message transform (SMT).
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html#set-up-filter
If I want to add the following configuration,
transforms=filter
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
transforms.filter.condition=value.op == 'u' && value.before.id == 2

How to config the filter for Debezium connector for PostgreSQL?
I'm using the Pulsar connectors as follows,
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/4.0.x/io-cdc-debezium/#example-of-postgresql
I'm try add configuration on debezium-postgres-source-config.yaml, but it doesn't work.

You're reading documentation for Debezium / Kafka Connect, which is not compatible with Pulsar Functions.
Based on my understanding, you'd setup an EntryFilter https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/develop-plugin/#step-2-implement-the-entryfilter-interface
Alternatively, you'd actually run a real Kafka Connect cluster and point it at Pulsar
